# Convert byte[] to List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: arrays, object, type-conversion

I am able to convert `List<Map<String,Object>>` to `byte[]`,
But when I convert `byte[]` back to `List<Map<String,Object>>` it gives only first object(key, value pair)

How do I iterate through byte array or ObjectOutputStream?

However, I tried `while (ObjectOutputStream#available() > 0 )` but `ois.available()` returns `0`

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("age", 12);
        map.put("name","gh");
        list.add(map);

        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("age", 20);
        map1.put("name","ty");
        list.add(map1);
        System.out.println(convertToObject(convertToByteArray(list)));
    }

    private static byte[] convertToByteArray(List<Map<String, Object>> resultSet) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
            for (Map<String, Object> map : resultSet) {
                out.writeObject(map);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteOut.toByteArray();
    }
    private static Object convertToObject(byte[] byteArr){
        Object obj = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       } 
       return  obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was iterating over `ObjectInputStream` and was hoping to get the entire List of map objects. 
When I iterate over `ByteArrayInputStream` I got the entire `byte[]` converted to `List<Map<String,Object>>`

Here is the complete method:

```
private static List<Map<String, Object>> convertToObject(byte[] byteArr){
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Object obj = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        //this is the chage I did 
        while(bis.available() > 0){
            list.add((Map<String, Object>)ois.readObject());
        }
        //change complete
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return  list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

> Any attempt to read object data which exceeds the boundaries of the custom data written by the corresponding writeObject method will cause an OptionalDataException to be thrown with an eof field value of true.

So you want to `try { while(true) {` and return success when you `catch (OptionalDataException e)`.